# Get indices from each row and merge with original data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data.frame

```
                   user_id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1           54449024717783 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
2          117592134783793 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
3          187145545782493 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
4          245003020993334 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
5          332625230637592 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6          336336752713947 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

what I would like to do is to create one column (and remove 1:9) and insert the column name where I have the value 1 , each user contain only column with the value 1 ,

If im running the following function:

```
rowSums(users_cluster(users_cluster), dims = 1)
```

it will summarize all the rows value but I need to duplicate it with the column name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
data.frame(user_id = df[, 1],
           name = which(t(df[, -1] == 1)) %% (ncol(df) - 1))

#           user_id name
# 1  54449024717783    3
# 2 117592134783793    6
# 3 187145545782493    3
# 4 245003020993334    6
# 5 332625230637592    2
# 6 336336752713947    2
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another `base` R option:

```
inds <- which(df[,-1]!=0,TRUE)
df$newcol <- inds[order(row.names(inds)),][,2]

df[,c(1,11)]
#       user_id newcol
#1 5.444902e+13      3
#2 1.175921e+14      6
#3 1.871455e+14      3
#4 2.450030e+14      6
#5 3.326252e+14      2
#6 3.363368e+14      2
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is `max.col` from `base R` as the user specified `each user contain only column with the value 1`

```
cbind(dat[1], ind = max.col(dat[-1], 'first'))
#          user_id ind
#1  54449024717783   3
#2 117592134783793   6
#3 187145545782493   3
#4 245003020993334   6
#5 332625230637592   2
#6 336336752713947   2
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse).

```
library(tidyverse)
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -user_id, -ID) %>%
  filter(Value == 1) %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  select(-Value, -ID) %>%
  as.data.frame()
dat2
#           user_id Column
# 1  54449024717783      3
# 2 117592134783793      6
# 3 187145545782493      3
# 4 245003020993334      6
# 5 332625230637592      2
# 6 336336752713947      2
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "                  user_id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1           54449024717783 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
2          117592134783793 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
3          187145545782493 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
4          245003020993334 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
5          332625230637592 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6          336336752713947 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)

dat <- as.tibble(dat) %>%
  setNames(sub("X", "", names(.))) %>%
  mutate(user_id = as.character(user_id))
```

Comment: @mtoto What is the correct output? Who defines the correct output?

Comment: your end result has reordered rows compared to the original dataframe

Comment: @mtoto The OP did not post the desired output, so what is wrong with order by column name? By the way, the OP was asking developing an answer based on column name, not index. I do not know why PoGibas changed the title of the OP's question. Although I reckon all the other answers are great and I gave them all upvotes, in my opinion, they are all based on index, not column names.

Comment: @mtoto Thanks for your comments. I have updated my answer to let the output has the same order in `user_id` as the original data frame although it is not the OP's requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Another base R solution:

```
df$ind = apply(df[,-1]>0,1,which)
df[,c("user_id","ind")]
```

Output:

```
       user_id ind
1 5.444902e+13   3
2 1.175921e+14   6
3 1.871455e+14   3
4 2.450030e+14   6
5 3.326252e+14   2
6 3.363368e+14   2
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution which uses `melt()` to reshape from wide to long format:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(DF), id = "user_id")[value == 1L][order(user_id), !"value"]

           user_id variable
1:  54449024717783        3
2: 117592134783793        6
3: 187145545782493        3
4: 245003020993334        6
5: 332625230637592        2
6: 336336752713947        2
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the sample dataset is already sorted by ascending `user_id`.

In case the sample dataset has a different order which should be maintained in the final result, it is necessary to remember that order by introducing a temporary row id:

```
melt(setDT(DF), id = "user_id")[, rn := rowid(variable)][value == 1L][
  order(rn), !c("rn", "value")]
```

or, alternatively,

```
melt(setDT(DF), id = "user_id")[, rn := rowid(variable)][, setorder(.SD, rn)][
  value == 1L, !c("rn", "value")]
```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread(
  "i                   user_id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  1           54449024717783 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  2          117592134783793 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  3          187145545782493 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  4          245003020993334 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  5          332625230637592 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  6          336336752713947 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
, drop = 1L)[, lapply(.SD, as.integer), by = user_id]
```